# How to handle asynchronous database inserts/updates

Tags: database, asynchronous

say I have a web application that fetches a user via REST:

```json
GET /users/me
```

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "John Doe",
  "email": "john.doe@email.com"
}
```

The web application has the ability to update this user in a form, e.g. change the `name`.
This is usually implemented with a REST endpoint that writes the change to the database (`UPDATE users SET name = 'My new name' where id = 1`) and return to result to the browser.

Business requires this system to scale to millions of concurrent users, and one effort to do so is by making these types of requests asynchronous. Changing `name` does not need to be an action that requires immediate response. It could be put on a queue and written to database when resources are available. The UI could reflect this by making the request, and then assuming that data was/will be updated. But if the user reloads the page, possibly old data will be fetched (because the change has not been written yet). We would then need to implement a storage in the browser to ensure the new `name` is persisted, and when "new" data is fetched on reload, compare something like a `timestamp` to know which value is latest.

What I'm wondering is, from someone with experience of this - is this a common way of doing it? What potential pitfalls should we be looking out for? What would be the alternative?

Comment: Adding to the first question:

How to deal with requests which depends on previously stored data?
For instance an UPDATE request that has to check something that's been sotred async and maybe is not stored yet, or the last updated data still in queue and you read old data.
Or related entities where you don't know if last data is stored yet or not.

Answer (score 0):

A common way of doing this is to return something like a processID that the client can use to check if the request was processed.
So the 'changeUserName' endpoint will return a processID and a 'checkProcessStatus' endpoint will return the status of the queued request.

In the interface you can show that the change is pending and poll once in a while to check if the status has changed.
So on the client side you can store the new name and the processID. When the processStatus changes to 'success' all is ok, when it fails you can always request the old name and notify the user something went wrong.

By the way: you can always implement this later when speed becomes a problem. First go for the easy way to see if you can get to a million users ;)

Edit: a little more about how this could work.
You create a queue for storing actions/things to process, for example a 'update user name to [new name] action'. This entry in the queue has a status and a processID and maybe additional information.
'checkProcessStatus' will just return the status of an entry, which is very cheap and will only return something like 'pending' and maybe a timestamp.
In the background the queue is handled and the status is updated to success, failed, or whatever. You can also provide additional information like error messages or updated values.
The next time a client uses 'checkProcessStatus' it will see the new status.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Thomas. A follow-up question. Wouldn't the 'checkProcessStatus' endpoint need to know the old value and the new value, and query what is persisted in the database to know if it has been processed? Or would it need to peek in the queue (Say rabbitmq). It sounds like an expensive operation.
Also, regarding your last comment: Is there any particular "easier" way to "scale" that you're thinking of?

Comment: `checkProcessStatus` must be as cheap as possible. So it only returns the status of the process in the queue. But when it is done you can return the result if you like, for example the new value that was stored. I will update my answer with some more information.